# JAX WS compatibility JRE 1.4

Tags: jax-ws, compatibility

- I have an application running over JRE 1.4.(Cannot upgrade, due to
  multiple reasons)
- I have another application which I need to invoke via a webservice.
- I have created the webservice client easily
  with JAX WS(wsimport, JDK 1.6) and am enable to invoke the
  webservice.

How do I integrate the webservice client with my current 1.4 JDK application?

Answer (score 0):

It's not posible because of Java 1.4 doesn't support annotations. You have to do it without them, so, use Axis. Look [here](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html)